# Screen black during phone call and it won't come back during call

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, phone-app

I have an Xperia XZs with Android 8. Lately I'm having problems while calling. When I start a call, the screen goes black immediately, and won't come back anymore during the call. The result is that when I'm in a menu where I need to chose a number, I can't, because the screen is black. I can't even hang up. Well, I can pull out the sim card, and that will end the call, but that means a restart.

I've installed a new dialer, and that seems to help a little, but the problem is still there.

**Is there any way I can get my dialer back to normal? Is this a new bug? I updated recently.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen protector has an opening for the proximity sensor. This opening collects dirt along the edges. After removing the dirt, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The proximity sensor take charge of your screen when making a call

Factory reset your phone or change to custom ROM. If the problem still exists, you've to change the proximity sensor on your phone.

Comment: That's an explanation of the behavior, but not a fix of this problem.

Comment: How does one change the proximity sensor of a phone? And why is it always a factory reset you recommend? Wouldn't it be better to try calibrating the sensor instead? Such an app could also detect if the sensor is working properly. If it does not, it might be necessary to sent it to a service center. A factory reset hardly helps then.